# load_administrator_email() codeigninter.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was trying to find out the error but I coudnt. I use codeigniter.
Here is the code

```
function send_emailalertstoAdmin($emailmessage,$ad_title)
{
     $this->load->model('user_model');
     $query_result =  $this->user_model->load_administrator_email();

    //$this->load->database();

    //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT users.email FROM users WHERE users.id =1');

    foreach ($query_result as $row)
    {           
        $email= $row->email;

        $successmasg = '';
        $from = "info@xxxt.com";                    
        $subject = "xxx ". $ad_title . " is Stolen"; 
        $message = $emailmessage;
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: xxxxx.com <info@xxxxt.com>' . "\r\n"; 

        $successmasg = mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

I got the following error.
Fatal error: Call to undefined method User_model::load_administrator_email()

Here is the load_administrator_email()  function

```
function load_administrator_email()
{
    $sql = "SELECT users.email FROM users WHERE users.id =1";
    $queryData = $this-> db->query($sql);   
    return $queryData -> result();
}
```

I was trying to find the error but I coudnt.
what I tried,
1. sql query is correct and it gives correct result.
2. when I hardcode email and comment calling load_administrator_email()  in first function ,email goes correctly.

please help me to correct this.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Load your model like this..

```
$this->load->model('user_model', '', TRUE);
```

Or else load it in the constructor

Comment: I am sorry. I hadnt to included load_administrator_email() methode in the model. I have missed to update server.